# How do I disable Firefox from converting all my color values to rgb?

Tags: html, firefox, colors, hex, rgb

So, the content I'm using is user generated -- so it can contain both hex and RGB values for dom element coloring. Parts of this user generated content is sent back to the server for analysis, so it's important that the color values remain in their original form.

How do I prevent firefox from converting everything to rgb?

*Using Firefox 11

Answer (score 3):

Hay this issue is now over in FF 45

just Hold the Shift button on the keyboard and click on the color circle and you will get all the formats you need

If you want to set as default Hax, RGB, Color name...
All you have to do is

1. open your inspector.
2. Go to toolbar options on the top right hand icon (looks like gear).
3. under inspector find default color unit and change it as desired.
   And you are done

[image: set as default Hax, RGB, Color name...]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to prevent ff. I suspect it is not even possible.

However, when you need to get back the original value, try to use html5 "data-"-attributes.
You are allowed to define own "data"-attributes and you define the semantic.

Comment: aye, but I'm not in control of the creation process of the content. That is CKeditor.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox development tools you can click settings icon and under Inspector you can change the default color units to Hex.